# FileSystem.mkdirs() return code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Does anyone know when [`FileSystem.mkdirs()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#mkdirs%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29)  returns `false`? Does it return `false` when the folder creation fails but no error is thrown, and if so, can someone give me an example of an occasion when this would occur? It returns `true` when the creation succeeds and throws an `Exception` under some conditions (ie. `IOException` due to insufficient permissions). However, it also returns `true` if the directory trying to be created already exists.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `FileUtil.mkdirs()` or `FileSystem.mkdirs()`?

Comment: My mistake, forgot to change the title, thanks.

Comment: [`RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs()`](https://github.com/facebookarchive/hadoop-20/blob/master/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem.java#L334) seems to be the only one which doesn't have a hard coded `return true;` in it. So this one would return `false` if there's already a *file* with the name of the directory.

Comment: @HannoBinder [FTPFileSystem](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0/org/apache/hadoop/fs/ftp/FTPFileSystem.java#FTPFileSystem.mkdirs%28org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission%29) also not hard-coded. Returns false if the FTP create directory command failed.